# 301 several (but not all) http to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a site of about 1.000 static pages, and I would like to see how moving from http to https will effect ranking for, say, 50 pages before I move the entire site.

Do I have to use the first code example below or is it enough with the second one? Or is there a better way to do it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page-1.htm/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page-2.htm/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page-3.htm/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# OR IS THIS ENOUGH:


Redirect 301 /page-1.htm https://www.example.com/page-1.htm
Redirect 301 /page-2.htm https://www.example.com/page-2.htm
Redirect 301 /page-3.htm https://www.example.com/page-3.htm
```

Comment: The second example won't work (unless you have the HTTPS in a separate VirtualHost and you apply this only to the non-HTTPS one).  The first example will, you just don't need the 2nd or third instance of `RewriteEngine On`.  starkeen's response is a great one

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single rule to redirect multiple pages of this format **page-n.htm**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+).htm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/page-$1.htm [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's good to know.

Do you know what's the best method if the filenames differ more than that? Let's say they're:

blahblah.htm
tjohoo.htm
whatever.htm

Comment: In that case you can use this pattern : **^(.+)\.htm$** and replace the target with **https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.htm**

Comment: I feel really embarrased asking this, but do you think you could give me the complete code with those 3 "dummy" file names?

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly want it in separate RewriteRule statements:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page-1\.htm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page-2\.htm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page-3\.htm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```